# Do I need to anchor this cabinet?

Tags: furniture, masonry, anchor

I have a massive wooden cabinet. Behind it is a masonry wall. Do I need to anchor the cabinet to the wall? There are walls to the left and right of it, so it cannot be pushed except from the front. If someone fell into it, it might fall backwards toward the wall, but I can't imagine anything pulling it forwards. We have a newborn but will probably move house before she is old enough to climb anything.

Comment: You anchor cabinets so they don't fall forward onto people.  If you have a masonry wall behind it, that's great.  Anchor it to that.  Why not?   If you haven't moved by the time your baby is, say, 18mos will you remember to do this, find the parts, and have the time?   What if some other member of your family pulls or climbs on it?

Comment: If you pull on it and it starts to tip forward, then it should be anchored.  A person might trip or fall and grab onto it.

Comment: Good points, thank you!

Comment: Congrats on the newborn! Since you seem to be a first-time parent, be aware that she may start pulling up on things in as little as 6-9 months. (Reference: 3 children that survived my parenting to make it all the way to adulthood.) Even at her tiny 15-20 pounds at that time, if she pulls on an extended drawer or open door, that's a fair bit of leverage force, and, well, you don't want to imagine the possible results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely anchor! anything that can fall should at least have some minor anchors to the wall, how many children have been killed from climbing a chest of drawers even things we consider small some less than 4’ tall and in most cases it won’t take much a toddler 50 lbs or less a seismic event well the same anchors may save your life if it is massive.